# watson discovery service always connecting to default service

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, watson-discovery

I have edited the code from following link

https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/discovery-nodejs

I have changed Environment variables and discovery service user name and password.

But while running the code it always goes to default service (the one it specified in the above link) not to my specific discovery service.
[Default service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVz4f.png)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean by the default service. If you are talking about the service endpoint then in the file app.js add a url specifier for the endpoint that you are using, when instantiating the DiscoveryV1 class.

```
const discovery = new DiscoveryV1({
  // If unspecified here, the DISCOVERY_USERNAME and
  // DISCOVERY_PASSWORD env properties will be checked
  // After that, the SDK will fall back to the bluemix-provided VCAP_SERVICES environment property
  // username: '<username>',
  // password: '<password>',
  version_date: '2016-11-09',
  url: '<endpoint>',
  qs: { aggregation: `[${queryBuilder.aggregations.join(',')}]` }
});
```

Comment: Hi chughts, 
Thanks for the reply.
I have updated my post. 'Default service' I meant , it is referring the discovery service that is mentioned in the sample code and not referring our 'required discover service'. I have mentioned the url but still not working.

Comment: look at the .env file : cf ssh APPNAME -c "cat .env"

Comment: in .env file I have only discovery username ,password, environment id and collection id

Comment: The application you are forking doesn't read url from the .env file. So you will need to add it as a parameter to the instantiation of the DiscoveryV1 object, as per the code I posted in my initial response.

Comment: in app.js i have url

Comment: Make sure that you have the latest version of the watson-developer-cloud SDK.